# Is there a way to PDF Page reorder according to any order of my choice?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

Is there a way to PDF Page reorder according to text string of my choice?
There are multiple sites that allow rearranging PDF pages by drag & drop. But, this process becomes to lengthy when I have a document of say 100 pages.
In case I need to print a 100 page PDF in such a way that it can be bound like a book, I need to rearrange these as the following order.

> 100,1,98,3,2,99,4,97,96,5,94,7,6,95,8,93,92,9,90,11,10,91,12,89,88,13,86,15,14,87,16,85,84,17,82,19,18,83,20,81,80,21,78,23,22,79,24,77,76,25,74,27,26,75,28,73,72,29,70,31,30,71,32,69,68,33,66,35,34,67,36,65,64,37,62,39,38,63,40,61,60,41,58,43,42,59,44,57,56,45,54,47,46,55,48,53,52,49,50,51

Here, the order is logical to be printed as a book, but it is not easy to utilise drag & drop to achieve this. Is there any way to rearrange the PDF in the above order of pages?

I have tried to use **Microsoft Print to PDF** and **Chrome Print** to do this, but this gives the output files as 1,2,3,.........,100 order.

Answer (score 0):

`cpdf in.pdf 100,1,98,3,2,99,4,97,96,5,94,7,6,95,8,93,92,9,90,11,10,91,12,89,88,13,86,15,14,87,16,85,84,17,82,19,18,83,20,81,80,21,78,23,22,79,24,77,76,25,74,27,26,75,28,73,72,29,70,31,30,71,32,69,68,33,66,35,34,67,36,65,64,37,62,39,38,63,40,61,60,41,58,43,42,59,44,57,56,45,54,47,46,55,48,53,52,49,50,51 -o out.pdf`